# Elliptic Curves with Complex Multiplication

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, complex-multiplication

So I've been reading about elliptic curves with CM recently. I am aware of the following theorem:

Let $E/\mathbb{C}$ be an elliptic curve and let $\Lambda=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z} \tau$ the corresponding lattice. We have two possible cases:

- $End(E)\cong\mathbb{Z}$
- $\mathbb{Q}(\tau)$ is a quadratic imaginary extension of $\mathbb{Q},$ and $End(E)$ is isomorphic to an order of $\mathbb{Q}(\tau)$

I understand the theorem completely, if we have an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ with CM, then $End(E)$ is isomorphic to an order of $\mathbb{Q}(\tau).$

My question is, what happens when we have an elliptic curve defined over an algebraic number field? As I understood, the same thing is true, $End(E)$ is isomorphic to an order of $\mathbb{Q}(\tau)$ (where $\tau$ is from the corresponding lattice as we look at the same elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{C}$), I just can't seem to find results about it.
Is it even true? Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: You mean when given an algebraic curve model ? The good Weierstrass equations are defined over $\Bbb{Q}(j(\tau))$ and the complex multiplication endomorphisms (those sending $z\to (a+b\tau) z$ with $b\ne 0$) are defined over $\Bbb{Q}(j(\tau),\tau)$. This can be seen from $(\wp(z),\wp'(z))\to (\wp((a+b\tau)z),\wp'((a+b\tau)z))$  where $\wp(z),\wp'(z)$ generate the function field of the complex torus, and are coordinates for a good algebraic model.

Comment: @reuns so by $End(E)$ in the above theorem we mean $End_{\mathbb{C}}(E)$?

Comment: For $E:y^2=x^3+x$ defined over (any extension of) $\Bbb{Q}$ then $End(E/\Bbb{Q})=\Bbb{Z},End(E/\Bbb{Q}(i))=\Bbb{Z}[i]$ (the $i$ endomorphism is $(x,y)\to (-x,iy)$). $E/\Bbb{Q}$ and $E/\Bbb{Q}(i)$ don't have the same function field, so they are kinda different curves, that's why I used this notation. For algebraic curves $End$ means isogenies $E\to E$ (defined by some rational functions), there are much more endomorphisms of the abstract group.

Comment: @reuns Thank you for the answer, but I still don't understand how this is the answer to my question. For example if we have a curve $E$ over (say) $K$ such that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=2$ with CM, what do we know about the endomorphism group? Is it still isomorphic to an order of some imaginary quadratic field?

Comment: Check Silverman's The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, Chapter 3, Corollary 9.4. Note usually when we write $End(E)$, we mean the $\bar{K}$-endomorphisms of $E$ (where $E$ is defined over $K$). The $K$-endomorphisms might be strictly smaller as the comment above shows.